# How can I set a default value in an HTMX prompt?

Tags: javascript, ajax, htmx

I want to know how can I set a default value when window.prompt window is opened.

```
<a href="#" hx-prompt="Type your age" hx-get="/set/age">My Age: ?</a>
```

window.prompt is blank. How can I set predefined age like `20`?

Comment: Unfortunately HTMX doesn’t implement that functionality: https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/blob/80e56294121cd4a89a5ab36c87868132076f0250/src/htmx.js#L3165

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTMX doesn’t let you do that, but here’s an extension that introduces the custom attributes `hx-ask` and (optionally) `hx-ask-default`:

```js
htmx.defineExtension('ask', {
    onEvent: function(name, event) {
        if (name !== 'htmx:configRequest')
            return;        

        const elt = event.detail.elt;
        const askElt = elt.closest('[hx-ask]') || elt.closest('[data-hx-ask]');
        
        if (askElt) {
            const question = askElt.getAttribute('hx-ask') || askElt.getAttribute('data-hx-ask');
            const suggestion = askElt.getAttribute('hx-ask-default') || askElt.getAttribute('data-hx-ask-default');
            const answer = prompt(question, suggestion || undefined);

            if (answer !== null) //null when canceled
                event.detail.headers['HX-Prompt'] = answer;
        }
    }
});
```

To be called like this:

```html
<body hx-ext="ask">
    <a href="#" hx-ask="Type your age" hx-ask-default="69" hx-get="/set/age">My Age: ?</a>
</body>
```

As you can see, it sends the `HX-Prompt` header just like the `hx-prompt` attribute. If you use both `hx-ask` and `hx-prompt`, you’ll get two prompts, but only the result of `hx-ask` will be sent, because it runs later.

Seems like a nice enough feature, someone should make a PR and add it to the official `hx-prompt` thing.

Comment: Thanks for your response, It is helpful but it doesn't work properly if cancel is pressed on prompt window and also not working with hx-vals .

Comment: so check for null and don’t add the header

Comment: I already did that by codes... but unable to resolve about hx-vals

Comment: Thank you @BenderBoy I have made some changes and your provided solution is working fine for me... 

Comment: Hi, thanks for the upvote. Sorry about the curtness earlier, I was afk. I added the null check to my answer for posterity, good point. What was the problem with `hx-vals`?

Comment: Nothing, hx-vals is working fine by default. I was mistaken.